# Why are spaces echoing as newlines?

Tags: bash, echo, jq

I've got this JSON data that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "loginId": "7638749",
    "customerprofileDetails": {
      "securityQuestions": [
        "What is your favorite sports team?",
        "What is your favorite song?",
        "Who is your favorite artist?"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I have a script where I pass in that file as the first argument.  The script looks like this:

```
for json in `cat $PWD/$1 | jq -cr '.[]'` ; do
    echo "$json"
done
```

For some reason, when I run this script, it outputs this:

```
> fileFromJson.sh tmp2.json
{"loginId":"7638749","customerprofileDetails":{"securityQuestions":["What
is
your
favorite
sports
team?","What
is
your
favorite
song?","Who
is
your
favorite
artist?"]}}
```

Why are those newlines there and what's causing this problem?  When I just run `cat $PWD/tmp2.json | jq -cr '.[]'`, it prints out on one line.  I'm using MacOS if that matters.

Comment: Background reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters . I'm not sure that this can be considered a duplicate: what were you trying to do with this for loop? The input is a single piece of JSON, what is there to iterate on?

Comment: @Gilles the real input has multiple elements.  I need to create a file with the loginId value and use the customerprofileDetails as its content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unquoted command substitution `` `cat $PWD/$1 | jq -cr '.[]'` `` does the following:

1. Run the command `cat $PWD/$1 | jq -cr '.[]'`. Which by the way is an overly complicated way of writing `jq -cr '.[]' <"$1"`, except that this variant doesn't break [if `$1` contains certain special characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) or is an absolute path.
2. Break the resulting string into whitespace-separated pieces. Your question is not very clear, but you seem to expect newline-separated pieces — that's not what an unquoted substitution does.
3. Treat each piece as a wildcard pattern and, if it matches one or more file name, replace that piece by the list of matching file names.

Steps 2 and 3 are colloquially known as the “split+glob operator” and [this is almost never what you want](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). [Always use double quotes around variable and command substitutions unless you know exactly why you need to leave out the quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

To process a file line by line in the shell, use a [`while read`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767#131767) loop:

```
jq -cr '.[]' <"$1" |
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done
```

But you may be better off piping into some other tool. Shells aren't good at processing large amounts of string data by themselves.

Comment: Thanks.  Why printf instead of echo?

Comment: @DanielKaplan See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: @dan I think that `echo` would work here because this is JSON in bash. `echo` may interpret its first argument as an option if it starts with `-` and some shells interpret backslash escapes.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `echo` always outputs a trailing newline.

You can pass the `-n` argument to `echo` to prevent it from doing so.

From `man echo`:

> -n     do not output the trailing newline

Edit:

The "issue" here is not in your `cat $PWD/$1 | jq -cr '.[]'` command, it's in the `echo` line itself, or more precisely, the `for` loop. With the `for` loop, you are splitting what you're passing to it (the output of the `jq` command) word by word.

So essentially, you're passing every single string that is separated by a whitespace one-by-one to the echo command, which will by default add a trailing newline everytime it is executed.

Comment: That worked, but I don't understand why.  Doesn't `jq -c` convert the json to a single line already?  Besides, there were never newlines between those words originally.  Why are there trailing newlines between spaces?

Comment: I'll edit my answer.

Comment: True (for bash, not for all other shells), but not relevant. Changing `echo "$json"` to `echo -n "$json" will remove the newlines but will not print the original. Changing to `echo -n "$json "` will _not_ print the original either. Consider the input `["hello * world"]`…

Comment: I have edited my answer.